# is there a way to consider only the non-zero values of median to calculate its value?

Tags: arrays, c

I have the code below and the median gives 89.0 when I enter the following:

40 20 90 90 80 70 61 60 50 40 20 10 61 70 30 90 70 80 40 50 100 59 -1

The values when sorted with the sort function are:

10 20 20 30 40 40 40 50 50 59 60 61 61 70 70 70 80 80 90 90 90 100

So the median should be much lower than 89.0. My guess is that the non-zero of count are being considered.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 1000

void frequency(int ScoresFromTest[], int size);
void sort(int ScoresFromTest[], int n);
float pPercentage(int ScoresFromTest[], int size);
float fPercentage(int ScoresFromTest[], int size);
float mean(int ScoresFromTest[], int size);
int mode(int ScoresFromTest[], int size);
float median(int ScoresFromTest[], int size);

int main()
{
    int  i, n, ScoresFromTest[SIZE] ;
    printf("Number of scores: ") ;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the numbers:\n") ;
    for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        scanf("%d", &ScoresFromTest[i]);
    int size = n;
    printf("%d",size);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", ScoresFromTest[i]);
    printf("\n");
    sort(ScoresFromTest, size);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", ScoresFromTest[i]);
    printf("\n");
    
    
    
   frequency(ScoresFromTest, size);
   sort(ScoresFromTest, size);
   printf("Passing %.2f \n", pPercentage(ScoresFromTest, size));
   printf("Failing %.2f \n", fPercentage(ScoresFromTest, size));
   printf("Mean %.2f\n", mean(ScoresFromTest, size));
   printf("Mode %d\n", mode(ScoresFromTest, size));
   printf("Median %.2f\n", median(ScoresFromTest, size));
    
}

void frequency(int ScoresFromTest[], int size)
{
    
   int scores[101] = { 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85,
       84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64,
       63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43,
       42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22,
       21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
   int count[101] = { 0 };
   int i,j;
       for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
           for (j = 0; j < 101; j++)
           {
               if (scores[j] == ScoresFromTest[i])
               {
                   count[j]++;
               }
           }
       }
   printf("score    frequency\n");
   printf("-----    ---------\n");
   for (i = 0; i < 101; i++)
   {
       if(count[i] > 0)
       {
           printf("%3d    %5d\n", scores[i], count[i]);
       }
   }
}


void sort(int ScoresFromTest[], int size)
{
   int i, j,temporary;
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       for (j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
       {
           if (ScoresFromTest[j] > ScoresFromTest[j + 1])
           {
               temporary = ScoresFromTest[j];
               ScoresFromTest[j] = ScoresFromTest[j + 1];
               ScoresFromTest[j + 1] = temporary;
           }
       }
   }
}

float pPercentage(int ScoresFromTest[], int size)
{
   int count = 0,i;
   float percent;
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       if (ScoresFromTest[i] >= 70 && ScoresFromTest[i] <= 100)
       {
           ++count;
       }
   }
   percent = (float)count/size*100;
   return percent;
}

float fPercentage(int ScoresFromTest[], int size)
{
   int count = 0, i;
   float percent;
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       if (ScoresFromTest[i] < 70 )
       {
           ++count;
       }
   }
   percent = (float)count / size * 100;
   return percent;
}

float mean(int ScoresFromTest[], int size)
{
    int i;
    float sum, m;
    
    sum = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += ScoresFromTest[i];
    }
    m = sum/size;
    return m;
    
}


int mode(int ScoresFromTest[], int size)
{
   int scores[101] = { 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85,
       84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64,
       63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43,
       42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22,
       21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

   int ticker[101] = { 0 };
    int i, j, largest;
    
    largest = 0;
    
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       for (j = 0; j < 101; j++)
       {
           if (scores[j] == ScoresFromTest[i])
           {
               ticker[j]++;
           }
       }
   }
   
   for (i = 0; i < 101; i++)
   {
       if(ticker[i] > 0)
       {
           if (ticker[0] < ticker[i])
           {
               largest = scores[i];
           }
       }
   }
   return largest;
}

float median(int ScoresFromTest[], int n)
{
   double m;
   int scores[101] = { 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85,
       84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64,
       63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43,
       42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22,
       21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

   int count[101] = { 0 };
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       for (j = 0; j < 101; j++)
       {
           if (scores[j] == ScoresFromTest[i])
           {
               count[j]++;
           }
       }
   }
   
   if (n % 2 == 1)
   {
       m = scores[n / 2];
   }
   else
   {
       m = (scores[n / 2] + scores[n / 2 - 1])/2.0;
   }
   return m;
}
```

Comment: what is the expected value?

Comment: Ignoring some details: at the end of your median() function, after "counting" the data, you are not using the input data, instead you just select the n/2th value from the scores[] array.  In this case you have 22 input values, and so you re seeing the 11th (index from zero)  value, which is 89.

Comment: "the non-zero of count" -- what does this mean?